# How to connect Joomla 2.5 to Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, joomla

I want to connect joomla 2.5 to a Postgresql database.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Postgres support native as of 2.5. Do you want to run a Joomla on Postgres or do you want to build a component that connects to another Postgres database?

Comment: When i setup joomla 2.5 i only  see  joomla support mysql and mysqli. I want to build a component that connects to Postgres database?

Comment: Officialy joomla (setup) is only supported on mysql and mysqli, if you want to build a component you could use PDO for example, depanding on your needs it won't be effective since you'll have 2 separate databases ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create file config for postgresql in `/database/`.

You can watch this particular topic on the [Google Groups Joomla Bug Squad](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/joomlabugsquad/LWQ0zyZ9PMg).